# Java Question Containts Abstract, Interface and Exception

Tags: interface, abstraction

Design an interface named `Colorable` with a void method named `howToColor()`.

Design a class named Triangle extending `GeometricObject` and implementing `Colorable`.

Triangle implements `howToColor` method to display the message "Color all three sides".

Triangle implements the`toString` method to display its color and its sides.

In a triangle, the sum of any two sides is greater than the other side. The Triangle class must adhere to this rule. Create the `TriangleException` class, and complete and implement the constructor of the Triangle class to throw a `TriangleException` object if a triangle is created with sides that violate the rule.

The output of the test program should be as indicated below.

```
    abstract class GeometricObject {

    private String color = "white";

    protected GeometricObject(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Color: " + color;
    }

    public abstract double getPerimeter();
}

class Triangle {

    private double side1, side2, side3;

    public Triangle(double side1, double side2, double side3) throws TriangleException {

    }

}

class TriangleException {

}
```

Code is testing:

```
try {
    Triangle t1 = new Triangle(1.5, 2, 3);
    System.out.println(t1.toString());
    System.out.println("Perimeter for t1: " + t1.getPerimeter());
    t1.howToColor();

    Triangle t2 = new Triangle(1, 2, 3);
    System.out.println(t2.toString());
    System.out.println("Perimeter for t2: " + t2.getPerimeter());
    t2.howToColor();
} catch (TriangleException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    System.out.println("Side1: " + ex.getSide1());
    System.out.println("Side2: " + ex.getSide2());
    System.out.println("Side3: " + ex.getSide3());
}
```

According to this code result must be:

```
Color: red Sides: 1.5, 2.0, 3.0
Perimeter for t1: 6.5
Color all three sides.
Triangle inequality violation!
Side1: 1.0
Side2: 2.0
Side3: 3.0
```

So it must be true for the input in the example. For example for `t2.getPerimeter()` statement we have to create a getPerimeter method by return value of side1 + side2 + side3. But t2 part does not belong to us it belongs to the user.

I couldn't answer this question I need your help. In the first step, I got an error. I can solve other parts but I couldn't solve throws Exception part. I tested original version of code in Eclipse (without any changing) but I get a throws Exception error. If you try the code like me you will get error too. Now How can I solve this problem, I'm new in Java.

Comment: Please add the error text to the question.

Comment: "No exception of type TriangleException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `class TriangleException` with `class TriangleException extends Exception`. All user-defined exception should be subclasses of `Exception`.

Comment: This solved my Exception error, thanks. I continue to solve the rest of the code. If I get any errors, I may write again. Thanks again.

Comment: @Zuko Please accept this answer if it solved your problem.